# EC2 hosted WordPress - GET request from domain to EC2 host denied. "net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

Tags: wordpress, amazon-ec2, network-programming, aws-application-load-balancer, mixed-content

I have Wordpress hosted via an EC2 instance with traffic from domain routed through an ALB with an ACM issues certificate.

I have been struggling with a "Mixed Content Error" which is causing my site theme/styles to not display when connecting through the domain and ALB. When connecting directly to the EC2 public IP, everything displays as expected. To resolve the HTTP/HTTPS mixed content error, I installed the SSL insecure content plugin which resolved the mixed content error message but presented this new issue.

When accessing the page from the Route53 domain name which directs to the ALB - these are the errors I encounter in the console.

```
"DOMAIN_NAME"/:29 
        
GET https://"EC2_Public_IP"/wp-includes/css/dist/block-library/style.min.css?ver=6.4.2 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

"DOMAIN_NAME"/:41 
                
GET https://"EC2_Public_IP"/wp-content/themes/generatepress.3.3.1/generatepress/assets/css/main.min.css?ver=3.3.1 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

There are a few other similar errors with different indexes and one separate error with a dropdown.

```
(index):13
 
GET https://"EC2_Public_IP"/wp-includes/js/wp-emoji-release.min.js?ver=6.4.2 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
t           @   (index):13
(anonymous) @   (index):13
Promise.then (async)        
(anonymous) @   (index):13
(anonymous) @   (index):13
```

I have tried removing the plugin and fixing the mixed content error through other means with no success. Hopefully someone here can help me dig a bit further into this.

Answer (score 0):

The mixed content error arises when certain static resources, such as CSS files, JavaScript, and images, are loaded using HTTP instead of HTTPS.

1. In your WordPress admin panel, navigate to `Settings > General` and
   ensure that both the WordPress Address and Site Address are
   configured to use `https://`.
2. URLs in your static content, like posts, CSS files, images, etc., that use `http://` need to be updated to `https://` to ensure secure
   connections. You can use a plugin like [Better Search Replace](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/) to
   locate and substitute all occurrences of `http://` with `https://`
   in your WordPress database.
3. In `wp-config.php`, you can enforce HTTPS with the following lines:

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https')  
    $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
```